# Data Structure Selection - Printing Filepaths

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, filepath, adjacency-list

I had a question regarding printing the names of files. Say I start with something like a list of strings such as

```
files = [['documents', 'pics', 'cool.zip'], ['documents', 'homework'], ['Desktop, 'documents', 'file.jpg'], ['awesome.jpg'], ['turtles', 'homework']]
```

Essentially this is a list of lists of file paths. I'd like to try to take this and organize it into a data structure that will help to identify the links between the file paths.

I was thinking that a Graph may be the best way to represent this, but typically i'e seen graphs start out with adjacency lists which is also a list of lists, but typically each sub list is a pair of items. Anyone have some feedback here on best data structure to use here? I'd ultimately like to reconstruct a Graph and then print out the contents of the Graph, depth first.

Comment: A colllection of related file paths is usually considered as a tree - which is a kind of graph.  Take a look at the RHS of windows file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, files are organised in a tree. You start with a "root" directory, which has a set of children, each of which is either a file, or a directory - which has its own set of children (or a link/shortcut, but they make things more complicated than it sounds like you need here)